# How HttpServlet can create threads without implementing Runnable or extending thread

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

As we know, when servlet receivies a request, it creates a new thread and inside the new thread, the service method is invoked. So with only one Servlet instance, many threads are invoked.

What I didn't understand is how `HttpServlet` is able to create threads of its own instance without implementing runnable or extending thread?

Can any one please clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As we know, when servlet receivies a request, it creates a new thread and inside the new thread, the service method is invoked. So with only one Servlet instance, many threads are invoked.

In fact, that is INCORRECT.  The web container typically maintains a bounded pool of worker threads to handle requests.  New threads don't get created for each new request.

> What I didn't understand is how HttpServlet is able to create threads of its own instance without implementing runnable or extending thread?

Basically, it doesn't.  `HttpServlet` does not create threads, and it is not a thread or a runnable.

The web container has implementation specific classes that implement `Runnable` or extends `Thread`.  These classes call the relevant methods on the (shared) `Servlet` instance.

Comment: Got it.. so a separte class which has servlet instance and implementing runnable or extending thread invokes the servlet's service method in a new thread.. Thanks for the clarification and also for the worker threads clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is handled by the Servlet Container (also called the Web Container).
The Servlet Container is responsible for maintaining the Servlet Lifecycle.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet

> Life cycle of a servlet
>
> 1. The container calls the no-arg constructor.
> 2. The Web container calls the init() method. This method initializes the
>      servlet and must be called before life
>      of a servlet, the init() method is
>      called only once.
> 3. After initialization, the servlet can service client requests. Each
>      request is serviced in its own
>      separate thread. The Web container
>      calls the service() method of the
>      servlet for every request. The
>      service() method determines the kind
>      of request being made and dispatches
>      it to an appropriate method to handle
>      the request. The developer of the
>      servlet must provide an implementation
>      for these methods. If a request for a
>      method that is not implemented by the
>      servlet is made, the method of the
>      parent class is called, typically
>      resulting in an error being returned
>      to the requester.
> 4. Finally, the Web container calls the destroy() method that takes the
>      servlet out of service. The destroy()
>      method, like init(), is called only
>      once in the lifecycle of a servlet.

Comment: I understand the above the lifecycle of servlet.. But my question is, technically, how is it possible to create a thread of Servlet class with it implementing runnable or extending thread?

Comment: There is nothing like a "thread of Servlet" only one Servlet instance which is used by all worker threads. Object instances do not belong to threads; they can be called from every existing threads - sometimes even concurrently which makes multi-threading programming so difficult.